# How can I change eclipse's Internal Browser from IE to Firefox on Windows XP?

Tags: eclipse

How can I change eclipse's Internal Browser from IE to Firefox on Windows XP?

To be more specific I need to change the Internal Browser instead of adding the External Browser through Preferences -> General -> Web Browser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know if this will help, but here's the SWT FAQ question [How do I use Mozilla as the Browser's underlying renderer?](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#howusemozilla)

Edit: Having researched this further, it sounds like this isn't possible in Eclipse 3.4, but [may be slated](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=173128) for a later release.

Answer (score 42):

In Preferences -> General -> Web Browser, there is the option "Use internal web browser". Select "Use external web browser" instead and check "Firefox".

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the list where you can check which browser to use is only for External Browsers. It says so just above that list. I need to change the Internal Browser.

Comment: Yep, external only selection.

Comment: The question was for internal browser, not external.

Answer (score 7):

You can find out the option for changing browser in `Window menu`.

See image at below.

[image]

This image can be easy to understand.

Comment: A had this menu before, but in Eclipse Luna (Java EE IDE for Web Developers, Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1) I do not see it. It is missing in "Customize perspective -> Menu visibility" too. In the preferences it is still here.
Any clue how to have it in some menu or toolbar?

Comment: I've just installed Luna 4.4.1 and I have that option, just like with previous versions of Eclipse.

Comment: This is not part of a vanilla Eclipse installation. It is probably added by one of the Web Development tools in your installation.

Answer (score 6):

I like the Aptana Browser Preview windo for this.

You can get it from their update site: http://download.aptana.org/tools/studio/plugin/update/studio/

After you install the Aptana plugin, open an Aptana project and there should be an option under help to install aptana features.  under other you will find a Firefox/XUL browser.  There may be a more direct way to install the XUL plugin, but the above procedure works.

Answer (score 1):

Window-->Web Browser--> Firefox