# Eclipse HTML: placeholder is not an attribute?

Tags: html, eclipse, placeholder

I am using the latest version of Eclipse Luna (for Java EE developers), and when I insert an `<input type='text' placeholder='test123'`, eclipse says "Undefined attribute name (placeholder).".

[image]
Why is it like that? Have I done something wrong? Is there a way of fixing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eclipse checks for html tags and attributes against the doctype. Make sure that you have given doctype on top. It will fix the problem.
Also, Eclipse uses IE internally. You can configure it to firefox/chrome for better tags and attribute comparison.

Refer to this [How can I change eclipse's Internal Browser from IE to Firefox on Windows XP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744404/how-can-i-change-eclipses-internal-browser-from-ie-to-firefox-on-windows-xp) for changing your browser.

Answer (score 13):

Add the `<!DOCTYPE html>` indicating that its HTML5, placeholder is a new element in HTML5 and doesn't exists on HTML4 or early versions

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input placeholder="aspdkpoas"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```