# Change Default Browser in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, browser, eclipse-luna, gae-eclipse-plugin

I'm using `Eclipse Luna` and I have created an app using the Google App Engine SDK.

When I'm trying to deploy my app to GAE, **Sign in to Google Services** window open and when I give my Google credentials it show another window with Account Permissions. But I can't click Accept and Cancel buttons in this window, because this window display that page using **Internet Explorer** embedded window. Due to issues in IE, those buttons are disabled.

So I change my browser from `Window => Preferences => General => Web Browser` to Firefox. But still **Sign in to Google Services** window is open in IE embedded window.

How can I change this to open in Firefox embedded window?

Comment: Pick the **external** web browser choice in that page -- i.e use a real browser (Firefox is fine) rather than an embedded window -- and you should avoid several headaches, such as the one blocking you now.

Comment: @AlexMartelli I have selected **external web browser**. But it still open in IE embedded window.

Comment: The same happens in Eclipse Mars and on a Mac a year later - 'links' in the Overview use an embedded AppleWebKit/601.4.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/522.0 that my corporate firewall does not like because it is outdated. Changing preferences to use a selected external (Firefox) browser causes some links to work but others do not. A web cache issue? I dunno.

Answer (score 1):

I think answer is update your IE7 , 8 to IE9.. it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to change the embedded browser in Eclipse. There is a [very old bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=173128) open to add this functionality, but it doesn't look promising. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/744826/3953357).

For now the solution is to to use an external browser, as was suggested above.